# what is the error in insert statement into mysql in python in the following example?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Iam trying to crawling web site then retrieve data from this web site and insert into table into mysql using python 3, the data that i want to insert in table is tuble and i implemented `get_article_details` function , it result data correctly. But i have a problem in insert statement as the following:

```
import pymysql
conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='root',password='')
cur=conn.cursor()
def save_data(data):
    
    cur.execute("insert into shereen.articles values" +str(data))
    conn.commit()
    print(data[0]+"   -->>saved")

def get_article_details(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    title=soup.title.text
    image=soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"articleimg"}).find('img')['src']
    writer=soup.find('div',attrs={"class":'pinfo'}).find('a').text
    article_date=soup.find('div',attrs={"class":'pinfo'}).find('span').text.replace("|"," ").strip()
    body=soup.find('div',attrs={'id':'NewsStory'})
    body.find('div',attrs={"class":'smsBoxContainer-v1'}).decompose()
    body.find('div',attrs={"class":'min_related'}).decompose()
    body.find('div',attrs={"class":'CoronaContainer inner noPaddding'}).decompose()
    article=[]
    for section in body.findAll('p'):
        article.append(section.text)
    article=''.join(article)
    keywords=soup.find('meta',attrs={'name':'keywords'})['content']
    data=(url,title,image,writer,article_date,article,keywords)
    save_data(data)
    return data
```

and the following error appears:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-026157a57db9> in <module>
----> 1 get_article_details("https://www.almasryalyoum.com/news/details/1994354")

<ipython-input-124-42023343dc13> in get_article_details(url)
     16     keywords=soup.find('meta',attrs={'name':'keywords'})['content']
     17     data=(url,title,image,writer,article_date,article,keywords)
---> 18     save_data(data)
     19     return data
     20 

<ipython-input-123-5db81833f7e7> in save_data(data)
      4 def save_data(data):
      5 
----> 6     cur.execute("insert into shereen.articles values" ,str(data))
      7     conn.commit()
      8     print(data[0]+"   -->>saved")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
    166             pass
    167 
--> 168         query = self.mogrify(query, args)
    169 
    170         result = self._query(query)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py in mogrify(self, query, args)
    145 
    146         if args is not None:
--> 147             query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
    148 
    149         return query

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 2):

The list of values should be surrounded with parentheses, and the strings, if any, needs to be quoted.

Bottom line, you do want to use parameters:

```
cur.execute('''insert into shereen.articles 
    (url,title,image,writer,article_date,article,keywords)
    values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', data)
```

Note that I (attempted to) enumerate the target columns in the `insert` statement. This is a best practice in SQL, which makes the statement easier to debug, more flexible and somehow resilient to DML changes of the target table.

Comment: it appears another error, TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting